# Expressing the trace of $A^2$ by trace of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ be a a square matrix. Is it possible 
to express $\operatorname{trace}(A^2)$ by means of $\operatorname{trace}(A)$ ? or at least
something close?

Comment: What kind of formula are you looking for? Even if $A$ is diagonal, this would be a difficult thing to do.

Comment: For $1\times 1$-matrices, there's a simple formula ;) Otherwise, even for diagonal matrices it's not simple.

Comment: It seems unlikely, as $A^2=B^2$ doesn't imply $A=B$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In general,

$\text{Tr}(A^2) = (\text{Tr}A)^2 - 2 \sigma_2(A), \tag{1}$

where $\text{Tr}$ denotes the trace of $A$, and $\sigma_2(A)$ is the coefficient of $N - 2$ in the characteristic polynomial $p_A(\lambda)$ of $A$, where $N$ is the size of $A$.  We have

$\sigma_2(A) = \sum_{i <  j}\lambda_i \lambda_j, \tag{2}$

where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . ., \lambda_N \in \Bbb C$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.  In this formula, repeated eigenvalues are admitted but are assigned distinct indices.

This result may be seen as follows:  factoring $p_A(\lambda)$, we have

$p_A(\lambda) = \prod_1^N (\lambda - \lambda_i) = \sum_0^N (-1)^i\sigma_i(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N) \lambda^{N - i}, \tag{3}$

where the $\sigma_i(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N)$ are the so-called elementary symmetric functions/polynomials in the $\lambda_i$.  This result is very well-known and is thoroughly discussed [in this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).  Inspecting (3), it is easily seen that

$\sigma_1(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N) = \text{Tr}A; \tag {4}$

and

$\sigma_2(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N) =  \sum_{i <  j}\lambda_i \lambda_j. \tag{5}$

$\sigma_k(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N)$ is the sum of $C_k^N = \frac{N!}{k! (N - k)!}$ terms, each being the product of precisely $k$ of the $\lambda_i$ with distinct $i$.  It is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $k$, and is evidently invariant under any permutation of the indices of the $\lambda_i$.  We also take

$\sigma_0(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N) = 1. \tag{6}$

An important fact for the present purposes is that, though the $\sigma_k(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N)$ may be expressed in terms of the $\lambda_i$, in the case of $p_A(\lambda)$ they may be had without explicit knowledge of the eigenvalues simply by obtaining the coefficients of $p_A(\lambda)$ from the defining equation

$p_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A); \tag{7}$

thus there is no ambiguity in referring to the $\sigma_k(A)$, as we have done above for the cases $k = 1, 2$.

Bearing these observations in mind, we recall that the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are precisely the $\lambda_i^2$ and thus

$(\text{Tr}(A))^2 = (\sum_i \lambda_i)^2 = \sum_i \lambda_i^2 + 2\sum_{i < j}\lambda_i \lambda_j = \text{Tr}(A^2) + 2\sigma_2(A); \tag{8}$

(1) follows by way of a minor re-arrangement of (8).  QED.

The full machinery of symmetric polynomials can actually be avoided by means of a simple induction whereby we may directly show that, for *any* polynomial $p(\lambda)$ with complex coefficients and $\deg p = N$, the coefficient of $\lambda^{N - 2}$ is $\sigma_2(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_N)$.  The case $N = 2$ is easily ratified, and serves as our base case:

$(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2) = \lambda^2 - (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2)\lambda + \lambda_1 \lambda_2; \tag{9}$

now suppose that

$\prod_1^k (\lambda - \lambda_i) = \lambda^k - (\sum_1^k \lambda_i)\lambda^{k - 1} + (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} \lambda_i \lambda_j) \lambda^{k - 2} + r(\lambda), \tag{10}$

where if $r(\lambda) \ne 0$ we have $\deg r(\lambda) \le k - 3$.  For $\lambda_{k + 1}$ arbitrary,

$\prod_1^{k + 1} (\lambda - \lambda_i) = (\lambda - \lambda_{k + 1}) (\lambda^k - (\sum_1^k \lambda_i)\lambda^{k - 1} + (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} \lambda_i \lambda_j) \lambda^{k - 2} + r(\lambda))$
$= \lambda^{k + 1} - (\sum_1^k \lambda_i)\lambda^k + (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} \lambda_i \lambda_j) \lambda^{k - 1} + \lambda r(\lambda)$
$- \lambda_{k + 1} \lambda^k + (\sum_1^k \lambda_i \lambda_{k + 1})\lambda^{k - 1} - (\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} \lambda_i \lambda_j \lambda_{k + 1}) \lambda^{k - 2} - \lambda_{k + 1}r(\lambda)$
$=\lambda^{k + 1} -(\sum_1^{k + 1} \lambda_i) \lambda^k +  (\sum_{1 \le 
 i < j \le k + 1} \lambda_i \lambda_j) \lambda^{k - 1}$
$-(\sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} \lambda_i \lambda_j \lambda_{k + 1}) \lambda^{k - 2} + \lambda r(\lambda) - \lambda_{k + 1} r(\lambda). \tag{11}$

Inspection of (11) reveals that the last three summands are all of degree $k - 2$ or less, since $\deg r(\lambda) \le k - 3$; thus (11) shows that the coefficient of $\lambda^{k - 1}$ in $\prod_1^{k + 1} (\lambda - \lambda_i)$ is in fact $\sigma_2(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, . . . \lambda_{k + 1})$, and the induction is complete.  QED.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Never I have forgotten you. My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  thank you, my friend.  Cheers!

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to cite this? I would appreciate it so much, because this is useful for my master's thesis.

Answer (score 11):

For $2\times 2$ matrices, the answer is $(\operatorname{tr} A)^2-2\det A$.

For an $n\times n$ matrix, the *characteristic polynomial* includes the trace, determinant and $n-2$ other functions in between.

The characteristic polynomial is the determinant $\det(\lambda I-A)$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  This turns out to be a polynomial in $\lambda$, of degree $n$.  The coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$ is $(-1)$ trace $A$, and the constant term is $(-1)^n\det A$.  The trace of $A^2$ can be written in terms of the trace of $A$ and the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-2}$.

Comment: I did some slight editing. Feel free to revert it if you don't like it. Also, you might want to explain how the characteristic polynomial relates to calculating trace.

Answer (score 3):

It is not. Consider two $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices, one with diagonal $\{1,-1\}$ and one with diagonal $\{0,0\}$. They have the same trace, but their squares have different traces.