# Is it possible to construct a matrix : $A^2 = J_{n}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $\Omega = Mat_{n\times n}(\{0,1\})$ - space of matrices of $1$s and $0$s.  We want to determine does there exist $A\in\Omega$ : $A^2 = J_n$, where $J_n$ is a matrix of ones. We suppose that there are standard arithmetical operations : ($\mathbb{R}$,+,$\cdot)$.

Actually I don't understand how to step it. I've thought about using some properties about spectrum of $J_n$, but it looks like failure moment.

Comment: uncertain about your notation. What are the elements of matrix $A$ permitted to be??

Comment: Are $0$ and $1$ here elements of $\Bbb Z$ or of $\Bbb Z_2$? (I'm not sure whether it makes a difference in whether the answer is positive.)

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit added

Comment: @TravisWillse mentioned.

Comment: The comment "We suppose that there is standard arithmetical operations..." doesn't quite answer my question, since $+$ and $\cdot$ are the standard notations for the usual ring operations of both of the rings I mentioned. Let me put it this way: Is it true that $1 + 1 = 0$ for your operation $+$?

Comment: @TravisWillse sorry! No modular arithmetic.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The trace of A would have to be $\sqrt{n}$...  this immediately rules out an awful lot of cases of n

Comment: @user8675309 why should it be $\sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: This question has an interesting graph-theoretic reinterpretation: For which $n$ is there a directed graph such that for every ordered pair $(v_1, v_2)$ of vertices there is precisely one directed path of length $2$ from $v_1$ to $v_2$?

Comment: Basically work over C, and suppose A exists— $A^2$ has one eigenvalue equal to n and all the rest are 0. This implies $A$ has one eigenvalue with modulus $\sqrt{n}$ and all else zero. The sum of eigenvalues is given by the trace and must be real non-negative for your matrix...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $n$ is a square (such as 4 in the example below), then the following pattern seems to work
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 1& 0& 0 \\
0& 0 & 1&1 \\
1&1 &0 &0 \\
0&0 &1 &1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
+ many row-column permutations.

Comment: Do you mean that each row has $\sqrt{n}$ $1$-s?

Comment: @openspace that seems to be necessary, but not sufficient. You cannot just change row 2 and 3 in my example

Comment: Yes look's like for $n^2$ we have : matrix with this pattern give us $J_n$. But why only $n^2$?

Comment: This was explained in the comments -- or look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506962/expressing-the-trace-of-a2-by-trace-of-a

Answer (score 7):

Note that $spectrum(J_n)=\{0,\cdot,0,n\}$; consequently, $spectrum(A)=\{0,\cdots,0,\pm\sqrt{n}\}$ and, necessarily,  $trace(A)=\sqrt{n}$. Thus, $A$ may exist only when $n$ is a square. In this last case, $A$ exists

For $n=1$, $A=[1]$.

For $n=4$,

[image]

For $n=9$,

[image]

and so on...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is negative when $ n = 2 $.  There, one finds by direct computation that the only matrices $ A $ which satisfy $ A^2 = J_2 $ are $ \pm \cfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} J_2 $, which does not belong to the desired space.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

$(J_n)_{ij} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} A_{ik} \cdot A_{kj}$

(By the way: Do(es a) row / column permutation(s) of $A$ change the result?)

Using the formula above and that the entries of $A$ are 0 or 1, it is clear that $(J_n)_{ii} = 1$ as requested if and only if there is (for every tuple $(i, j)$) exactly one k such that $a_{ik}$ and $a_{ki}$ = 1.
How does $A$ then look like? Try now a proof by contradiction.