# Trace of $A^4$ in terms of Tr$(A^3)$, Tr$(A^2)$ and Tr$(A)$ for a 3x3 matrix

Tags: matrices, trace

If $A$ is a 3x3 matrix, can Tr$(A^4)$ be related to Tr$(A^3)$, Tr$(A^2)$, and Tr$(A)$, where Tr is the trace of the matrix?

If so, how can we prove it? A similar question has been answered in [Expressing the trace of $A^2$ by trace of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506962/expressing-the-trace-of-a2-by-trace-of-a?newreg=e27c495cb5b441b1aa69bdedc867e3da).

Comment: Use Cayley-Hamilton theorem to express $A^4$ .. and take trace on both sides.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $tr(A^k)=\sum \lambda_i^k$ where the $\lambda_i$s are the eigenvalues of $A$ ?

Comment: Same question as Exodd: if you don't show that you have at least attempted something, you will get no answer...

Comment: Yes, the Cayley-Hamilton theorem helps to get an expression for Tr$(A^4)$. Thank you. 

And I was trying to expand Tr($A^2$) in terms of the elements and see if I can generalize the result somehow.

Comment: Not only for $Tr(A^2)$. Mutiply the Cayley Hamilton result by $A$, then take the trace: you will be able to connect the $Tr(A^k)$ for $k=1,2,3,4$