# Trace property of PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The following property is claimed:
$$
\sum_{i \neq j} a_{ij}^2 < (Tr(A))^2
$$
where $A$ is a PSD matrix, and $Tr(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}$ is its trace.

Any hints on how to use PSD properties to show that this is true?

Comment: you are evidently working over $\mathbb R$ so a definition of PSD is needed.  If $A$ is allowed to be skew-symmetric then this inequality is false.  It follows that if $A$ is allowed to be non-symmetric, then this inequality is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have the following
$$\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2 = \Vert A \Vert_F^2 = \mathrm{Tr}(A^T A).$$
Assume that $A$ is positive semidefinite (taking symmetry to be a part of this definition so that $A^T A = A^2$), which has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \geq 0$. The trace of $A^2$ can be related to the square of the trace of $A$ by (see [Expressing the trace of $A^2$ by trace of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506962/expressing-the-trace-of-a2-by-trace-of-a)):
$$\mathrm{Tr}(A^2) = (\mathrm{Tr}(A))^2 - \sum_{i \ne j} \lambda_i \lambda_j$$
In particular, since $A$ is positive semidefinite, $\mathrm{Tr}(A^2) \leq (\mathrm{Tr}(A))^2$. Putting these two facts together, we have $\sum_{i, j} a_{ij}^2 \leq (\mathrm{Tr}(A))^2$. If we want a strict inequality, then we can assume that $A$ is non-trivial (i.e. it is non-zero). This implies that the diagonal of $A$ is non-zero so that in particular, $\sum_{i \ne j} a_{i,j}^2 < \sum_{i, j} a_{i,j}^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is PSD, its two-rowed principal minors are nonnegative. Therefore
$$
\left(\sum_ia_{ii}\right)^2-\sum_{i\ne j}a_{ij}^2
=\sum_ia_{ii}^2+\sum_{i\ne j}(a_{ii}a_{jj}-a_{ij}^2)
\ge0
$$
and tie occurs in the inequality above only if $A\ne0$.